# My code runs into errors with a nested for loop in Visual code but works out fine with other online C++ compliers, why?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Below is a part of my code. The purpose of this portion is to prompt the user for two players' input, either "X" or "O", in any location of the 3x3 array, simulating two people playing tic-tac-toe. In Visual Studio, it complied alright, but it only prompts the user for input one time, doesn't iterate the nested for loop why? If I run the code without the inner for loop (which is used to prevent any duplicated index of the array), the program runs with the for loop.

What's wrong with my code?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 3;
    const int COLS = 3;
    const char *values[ROWS][COLS];
    int player_iteration;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int counter_x;
    int counter_y;
    //ask the choose of player 1 and player 2 back and forth for a total of 9 times
    for (player_iteration = 0; player_iteration < 9; player_iteration++)
    {   
        //player 1
        if (player_iteration % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter Player 1's choose: row colum" << endl;
            cout << "row: " ;
            cin >> rows;
            
            cout << "colum: ";
            cin >> cols;

            //check for input validation
            while (rows < 0 || rows > 2 || cols < 0 || cols > 2)
            {
                cout << "Your input is invalid, try again!" << endl;
                cout << "row: " ;
                cin >> rows;
                
                cout << "colum: ";
                cin >> cols;  
            }

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < player_iteration + 1; i++)
            {
                if ( strcmp(values[rows][cols], "*O") == 0 ||  strcmp(values[rows][cols], "*X") == 0)
                {
                    cout << "Your input is duplicated, try again!" << endl;
                    cout << "row: " ;
                    cin >> rows;
                
                    cout << "colum: ";
                    cin >> cols;

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            values[rows][cols] = "*O";
        }

        //player 2
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter Player 2's choose: " << endl;
            cout << "row: " ;
            cin >> rows;

            cout << "colum: ";
            cin >> cols;

            while (rows < 0 || rows > 2 || cols < 0 || cols > 2)
            {
                cout << "Your input is invalid, try again!" << endl;
                cout << "row: " ;
                cin >> rows;
               
                cout << "colum: ";
                cin >> cols;
            }

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < player_iteration + 1; i++)
            {
                if ( strcmp(values[rows][cols], "*O") == 0 ||  strcmp(values[rows][cols], "*X") == 0)
                {
                    cout << "Your input is duplicated, try again!" << endl;
                    cout << "row: " ;
                    cin >> rows;
                
                    cout << "colum: ";
                    cin >> cols;

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            values[rows][cols] = "*X";
        }
    } 
}
```

This is the command I run to complie and execute the program

```
cd "c:\Users\xueyi\Desktop\Sac_City\C C++\" ; if ($?) { g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile } ; if ($?) { .\tempCodeRunnerFile }
```

On the terminal window
After I enter the first row and colum value, the program stopped right there, and a few second later, it exits the program.

Corrected the declaration and initialization of the array

`const char *values[ROWS][COLS] = { {"*A", "*A", "*A"} , {"*A", "*A", "*A"}, {"*A", "*A", "*A"}};`

Comment: Did you try some debugging? for example using breakpoint? or add some extra `cout` to check behavior of loops?

Comment: Where do you initialize `values`?

Comment: @ sorosh_sabz I tried to run the debugging tool, but it popped up a window says 
 something \build\Debug\outDebug does not exist.

Comment: @G.M. I did not initialize it at the first place, but the user will do

Comment: Will they? Are you really sure that, say, `strcmp(values[rows][cols], "*O") == 0` will be executed *after* `values[rows][cols] = "*O";`? Please consider following the guides at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference before writing any more code.

Comment: Well worth the time spent getting the debugger working because it will help you solve mistakes like this in a fraction of the time you could otherwise spend.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you! It works after I initialized the array, but something confused me. I declared all the elements with "*A", but then after the user gave the value for row and column, the "*A" is being replaced with "*O" at the location the user pointed to. How could that happen? Since the array is a constant, which it shouldn't be able to be modified...

Comment: The array is *not* a constant, it's an array of *pointers to const* char. You can change `value[row][col]` (it will point to another string literal), but *not* `value[row][col][0]` (a single char in the string).

Comment: @Bob I read the direction on setting up the C++ debugger, but still don't understand how to set it up. It says "add the miDebuggerPath property and set its value to the location of the corresponding gdb.exe for your Cygwin or MinGW environment." and in my launch.json file, there is a line says ````"miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe"```` , I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Please append an edit section to your question showing exactly *how* you initialize `...all the elements with "*A"`.  As per the comment by @Bob__ the details are important here.

Comment: You could initialize all the pointers to _nullptr_ (or even just initialize the array with {} after its declaration, which initializes them too) and then instead of doing a strcmp to see if it's one of two known values, you could just check that the pointer is not null.

Comment: Do not change the title to include "solved". If there is no current answer that "solved" the question, write your own. Then mark the answer that solved the question as "accepted".

Comment: @Chris Uzdavinis Thank you so much! I completely forgot the pointer here. This is a way better solution than what I have done.